# How to create a loop so that it recognizes the loader element and when it disappears, continue with my process. In selenium with Java

Tags: java, selenium

I have this code to recognize an element, but I want to put it in a loop for when the element no longer exists continue my process

/** Wait for an element to be visible for a specific period of time */
@Then("^I wait element (.*?) to be visible$")
public void waitForElementVisible(String element) throws Exception
{
functions.waitForElementVisible(element);
}